# problem in geom_line when colored based on a categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create "a single line plot" of speed vs time. I wish to color the line based on the `categ`.

`categ` is a factor variable which can take value - 0, 1, 2.

But I am getting three line plots based on `categ`

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(time = 1:100,
              speed = 20 + runif(100),
              categ = factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 3, prob = 0.1)))


ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = time,
           y = speed,
            color = categ)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work the different colored segments need to belong to the same `group`:

```r
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = time, y = speed, color = categ, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The reason behind this is that when you use the `color` or `fill` aesthetics, the `group` aesthetic is defined by default. In most cases it's what we want, but in rare cases like this one it isn't, `group = 1` (where `1` is arbitrary) overwrite this default so we consider a single group.